# Best way to make biblatex's \printbibliography compatible with scrlttr2

Tags: biblatex, scrlttr2

I am trying to use biblatex together with the scrllttr2 class. The following MWE

```
\documentclass{scrlttr2}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{A2012,
author = {Author, A},
title = {An interesting paper},
journal = {Journal},
year = {2012},
volume = {2},
pages = {70--76},
}

\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}

\begin{letter}{XXX
}


\opening{To whom it may concern,}

\cite{A2012}

\closing{Kind regards
}

\end{letter}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

fails, because the `\printbibliography` command triggers the use of `\section`, which is not defined for letter classes. I can make the file work by using  `\printbibliography[heading=none]`, but this also kills the default heading. What is the best way to make the code run while still getting the default (language-specific) heading?

Comment: Define a new (unnumbered) level, \section, for the letter class, via the `titlesec` package?

Comment: You could define a new bibliography heading `\defbibheading{letterbib}[\refname]{#1}` or `\defbibheading{letterbib}[\bibname]{#1}` (the difference being the title: in English it is either "Bibliography" or "References") and use that via `\printbibliography[heading=letterbib]`. Where you can replace the part in `{#1}` by any formatting `scrlttr2` allows for. So you could go for `\defbibheading{letterbib}[\refname]{\textbf{#1}}`.

Comment: **NOOOOOO, don't use `titlesec`!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!**

Comment: @moewe Yours is the most obvious and simplest solution. Please make that an answer :-)

Comment: @Johannes_B why the `titlesec` comment? is that a generic comment against the use of `titlesec` or just in this case? care to elaborate?

Comment: @ArTourter `titlesec` is incompatible with KOMA and breaks several functionalities. When using, you get a huge warning in the log, but more and more users ignore warnings.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The trouble is that `scrlttr2` does not provide a `\section` command (which `biblatex` uses by default for the bibliography heading).

We can define our own heading though via

```
\defbibheading{letterbib}[\refname]{#1}
```

We can change `\refname` for `\bibname` here - `\refname` prints "References" while `\bibname` prints "Bibliography".
You can let your imagination run wild in the `#1` part and use any formatting you like, for example `\defbibheading{letterbib}[\refname]{\textbf{#1}}`.

We then use this new heading in `\printbibliography` like so

```
\printbibliography[heading=letterbib]
```

Answer (score 3):

Use the classes and packages, that do the job. ;-)

You can also load personalised `lco` files using `\LoadLetterOptions`, you just cannot do it globally.

[image: jpfeiferLcoScrletterBib]

```
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.lco}
    \setkomavar{fromname}{j pfeifer}
    \setkomavar{fromaddress}{duckburg}
\end{filecontents}
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{scrletter}
\LoadLetterOptions{\jobname}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{A2012,
author = {Author, A},
title = {An interesting paper},
journal = {Journal},
year = {2012},
volume = {2},
pages = {70--76},
}

\end{filecontents}

%\defbibheading{jpfeifer}{\large\bfseries\noindent MY BIB TITLE}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\begin{document}

\begin{letter}{XXX}

\opening{To whom it may concern,}
\cite{A2012}

\closing{Kind regards}

\printbibliography%[heading=jpfeifer]
\end{letter}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this is only an option if you are not having your own personalized `.lco` file that requires `scrlttr2`. Otherwise, switching classes is problematic

Comment: @SoundsOfSilence Still a valid solution, you should keep it. I waited with my upvote though ;-)

Comment: @jpfeifer updated

Comment: @Johannes_B: Nope... I am more and more unhappy with the KOMA classes and the scarce documentation

Comment: @Johannes_B Your suggestion works in general, but personalised `lco` files are not 100% compatible between `scrletter` and `scrlttr2`. Thus, I prefer @moewe solution.

Comment: @jpfeifer The solution provided by moewe is the simplest. But i am interested where incompatibilities are. Can we discuss this in the chat?

Comment: @Johannes_B I don't have the necessary reputation for the chat. But I am essentially trying to use https://github.com/momu/xetex-briefvorlage-internetmarke

Comment: @jpfeifer you will soon have ;-) Let me take a look at the project.

Comment: @jpfeifer If i load package `scrletter` the thing works like a charm. You have to take a look at [Customizing the letterhead using 'firsthead' in scrlttr2 (vertical positioning issues)](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/233265). But you need to do that anyway.

Comment: @Johannes_B Strange. I keep getting `! Undefined control sequence.
\KV@KOMAarg.definelayer@background ...teProcessed
                                                  \scrlayer@testunexpectedar...
l.1520 \newpairofpagestyles{scrheadings}{}`

Comment: I bet you don't have an up to date KOMA version. I forked and updated https://github.com/johannesbottcher/xetex-briefvorlage-internetmarke

Comment: @Johannes_B You were right, I had installed the most recent version of KOMA, but Windows had cached an old version in `AppData\Roaming\Miktex`. After deleting it, it works.