# Insert (and ref) uncompressed PDF literals in Latex document?

Tags: pdf, revision-control

I'm having a document whose source files are kept in `git`, and I'd like something similar to [Print subversion repo number on each page](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/87322/print-subversion-repo-number-on-each-page) ... I've already managed to pull the information I need and show it in the doc - except there's one problem: pretty much either `svn` or `git` require you to commit first, then re-build the PDF, so that you can access the latest revision number/ID (to insert it in the document PDF).

Now, I have a script, that automatically uploads the document PDF to a location, whenever a commit has been (successfully) made. If I want to include versioning info in there - I'd have to run `pdflatex` *yet again* after a commit has been made, and before upload has commenced; given that the document is *huge*, that would mean I'd have to wait extra half-a-minute to a minute each time I commit, which would irritate me immensely `:)`

So this is what I was thinking: if there was something like a PDF "string" variable, which could end up uncompressed in the output PDF during the `TeX`ing step; then I could simply use `sed -i` or something to replace it's content (here the revision info) inline using minimal time, right after a commit is made.

Here is what I mean: if I look at a typical PDF produced by `pdflatex` with `less -L`, I usually get something like this:

```
%PDF-1.5
%<D0><D4><C5><D8>
3 0 obj
<<
/Length 463       
/Filter /FlateDecode
>>
stream
xڭ<95>OO<E3>@^L<C5><EF><F9>^T> ...
```

That is, the very first object definition is "plain text", but its contents are a compressed stream... (so in principle I could unpack those, and replace content there, but since I'm trying to make it as simple as possible, I'm not interested in that).

Now, the PDF spec doesn't really have a "string variable":

- [Is there a text string variable type in Adobe PDF specification? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27092964/is-there-a-text-string-variable-type-in-adobe-pdf-specification)

... but it does have an `XObject`, which you can define once, and then re-use each page with `Do`: the problem with it is that is absolute (but I'd live with just bottom left placement).

So this is the thing; if I could instruct Latex to insert the `XObject` definition, e.g.:

```
6 0 obj
  << /Type /XObject
     /Subtype /Form
     /FormType 1
     /BBox [ 0 0 1000 1000 ]
     /Matrix [ 1 0 0 1 0 0 ]
     /Resources << /ProcSet [ /PDF ] >>
     /Length 58
  >>
stream
  %70 50 TD     % without this `TD` setting, `/A Do` places this in 0,0 - bottom left corner
  /F1 12 Tf
  (Hello, world!) Tj
endstream
endobj
```

... at the start of the PDF document, in *uncompressed* format; and then if I use say `fancyhdr` to insert `/A Do` in every page; then once the PDF document is built, I could basically just do `sed -i 's/(Hello, world!)/(rev. 117)/' out.pdf` after the commit is made, and be done with it.

(Of course, this isn't all - we'd need to insert also, say:

```
/XObject  <<
          /A 6 0 R  % XObject /A is obj 6 0
>>
```

... in the `/Page` dictionary (not sure if it can reside in `/Pages`), but that doesn't really need to be uncompressed.)

So, in general - is this kind of PDF intervention possible with LaTeX engines (`pdf`, `lua`, `xe`)?

Comment: You may try [`pdftk`](https://www.pdflabs.com/tools/pdftk-server/) (`stamp` or `background` operations).

Comment: Or you may try the [`pdfpages` package](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/pdfpages/)...

Comment: Why not change the script so that it compiles and uploads the PDF and no need to compile it before committing? (You probably need 2 compilations for update - at least I do.)

Comment: Thanks all; @PaulGaborit - I know `pdftk`, but didn't think of it in this context, that might probably be the best process-wise (but it will kill the `/Producer (pdfTeX-1.40.15)` document tag which I otherwise like `:)`)... `pdfpages` will still require recompilation as far as I know?

Comment: @cfr - the build script already does, say `pdflatex; biber; pdflatex; pdflatex`, and my commit script already uploads the pdf without compilation; the thing is, I'd like the "latest" (or "current") revision number/ID printed in the doc, and that number/ID is not available until the commit is made (which implies another recompilation after the commit, to get the right number/ID inside)... Cheers!

Comment: Actually, `/Producer (pdfTeX-1.40.15)` _is_ uncompressed in the PDF doc, so I might just insert the number/ID in there - it will be visible, but not printed in the doc...

Comment: I meant: why not change the scripts? Presumably the scripts are not set in stone. So if it is better for you to commit and then re-compile, why not configure your scripts to do that before uploading the PDF?

Comment: @sdaau `pdfpages` can add an ID on each page of a preexistent PDF document.

Answer (score 2):

You can use

```
\pdfinfo{/myversion (0.00.00)}
```

to include the Name `/myversion` (*you should use some other handle that's unique to you;* ideally you would [register a name prefix with Adobe/ISO](https://www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/pdfregistry_v3.pdf)) with the uncompressed string `0.00.00` in the info dict of the resulting pdf. You can then easily replace the `0.00.00` with your current version (e.g. with `sed`), but the replacement must have the same length.